# jquery mobile & swipe.js

Tags: jquery-mobile, ios6, swipe

I created a carousel with swipe.js , it works fine in iOS4 and iOS5. But in iOS6, without acceleration of hardware, when we swipe, there is a lag that can not be accepted. 
I have tried to create a carousel without jquery mobile, the performance is really great, but when we use JQM and listview (data-role="listview"), it became slower and the more elements in the list, the slower carousel is.

In html code, we have a carousel list and a normal listview, it seems if there are more elements in the listview, the carousel swipe will be slower. and they are two elements independent.
Here is html code

```
<div id='slider' class='swipe' style='width:250px'>
  <ul>
    <li style='display:block'><div>1</div></li>
    <li style='display:none'><div>2</div></li>
    <li style='display:none'><div>3</div></li>
    <li style='display:none'><div>4</div></li>
    <li style='display:none'><div>5</div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and a normal list view

```
<section class="nav_univers">
  <h1>Toutes les catégories</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul class="categories" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
      <li>Livre<a class="xt_books"></a></li>
      <li>Musique<a class="xt_music"></a></li>
      <li>Video<a class="xt_video"></a></li>
      <li>Jeux<a class="xt_video_games"></a></li>
      <li>AAA<a class="xt_phone_gps"></a></li>
      <li>QQQ<a class="xt_computing"></a></li>
      <li>DDS<a class="xt_multimedia"</a></li>
      <li>VVV<a class="xt_home"></a></li>
      <li>GGG<a class="xt_sports"></a></li>
      <li>HHH<a class="xt_mode"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav> 
</section>
```

and with Swipejs to create an object 
var slider1 = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'));

You can find our site here:

www.priceminister.com with user agent set to mobile device.

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem,

Change your css with :

```
.swipe
{

    ....
    ....

    /* IOS6 issue*/
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```